# Pandas: conditional sum with group by

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have found this question a couple of times, but I can't seem to make the answers work for my specific case, so I hope someone can help me.

I have the following table (apologies if it doesn't look correct I really tried):

```
ID  Reservation_Date  Booking_Date  Pax
0   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    4
1   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    5
2   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    2
3   2020-06-12        2020-06-09    5
4   2020-06-11        2020-06-02    6
5   2020-06-11        2020-06-02    1
6   2020-06-11        2020-06-10    3
7   2020-06-11        2020-06-10    5
```

Can be generated with:

```
    data = {
    'Reservation Date' : ['2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-11','2020-06-11', '2020-06-11', '2020-06-11'],
    'Booking Date' : ['2020-06-04', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-10', '2020-06-10'], 
    'Pax' : [4,5,2,5,6,1,3,5]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Reservation Date','Booking Date','Pax'])
```

What I want to achieve is to sum up the pax, grouped by reservation date but only where the difference between booking date and reservation date is equal to or greater than 7.

There are 2 outputs I would be happy with.

1. is where the column reservation date is aggregated and contains 1 record for each date, with the sum of pax that reserved for that date taking into account the booking date has to be 7 or more days before the reservation date
2. Where the records are the same, but there is a column added with the sum of pax (same as option 1) but it states the same sum for the same reservation dates on different lines.

On dates where there are no pax that booked 7 days before reservation date, the pax need to be 0.

So example output for option 1 would be:

```
ID  Reservation_Date  Booking_Date  Pax
0    2020-06-12       2020-06-04    11
1    2020-06-11       2020-06-02    7
```

and option 2:

```
ID  Reservation_Date  Booking_Date  Pax  Pax_Agg
0   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    4    11
1   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    5    11
2   2020-06-12        2020-06-04    2    11
3   2020-06-12        2020-06-09    5    11
4   2020-06-11        2020-06-02    6    7
5   2020-06-11        2020-06-02    1    7
6   2020-06-11        2020-06-10    3    7
7   2020-06-11        2020-06-10    5    7
```

I already tried creating a boolean value 'cond' with:

```
df['cond'] = (df['Reservation_Date']-df['Booking_Date']).dt.components.days >7
```

and using this as input on my groupby, but I couldn't make it work.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your date columns to dates using astype. You can then filter your dataframe using a mask. Finally, group on reservation date and sum your target column:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'Reservation Date' : ['2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-11','2020-06-11', '2020-06-11', '2020-06-11'],
'Booking Date' : ['2020-06-04', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-10', '2020-06-10'],
'Pax' : [4,5,2,5,6,1,3,5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Reservation Date','Booking Date','Pax'])
df = df[df['Reservation Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') >= df['Booking Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') + pd.Timedelta(7, unit='D')]
df = df.groupby(['Reservation Date'])['Pax'].agg('sum')
print(df)
```